# Does NFS download files to the client or does the client access them remotely on the NFS server?

Tags: nfs, nfsclient

I've been studying NFS and what I don't understand is this: after the client receives the filehandle from the server (all the way at the end of the whole NFS/mountd/NFSd etc. communication process) is the file data then written somewhere on the client?  And then the client reads/writes to that file on the client and then sends it back over the network to the server?  Or is the client reading and writing to this file on the server over the network?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As name says NFS (network File system) means accessing the files residing on the server. So every client NFS request either READ/WRITE will fetch the data from server over the network. Usually all NFS client implementaions will use some File caching/data caching mechanism. Once the data is read from server, it could store the data in its own cache (like buffer cache etc) for subsequent reads so as to improve the performance. As long as the client cache is valid, it doesn't need to go and fetch the data from server again and again.